# I emailed a colleague about a minor mistake, which was then fixed, but never got a reply. [ Did I annoy her? / Did I do anything wrong? ]

Tags: communication, mistakes

In our big company we have a media department which is monthly creating a company magazine with various articles. Over the last two magazines, I noticed that the name of a new software is not written correctly. As our department is responsible for the rollout of the new software, I wrote an email to the person who wrote the articles in both magazines and stated out politely how the software is written correctly in order to prevent confusion in future. I never met the author of the articles in person nor had contact with her before (big company as I said). However, I did not get any answer from her, but at least the name of the software is now written correctly.

What have I done wrong? Why did I annoy the person? I just wanted her to help doing her job better. How should I have done that?

Comment: Why do you think, she is annoyed?

Comment: Were you expecting an answer? Why? People often refrain from writing 'thank you' emails. Was there more to discuss?

Comment: Well in our country it is common to either confirm or even say "thanks" in such cases.

Comment: She changed the article to now write the correct spelling. So it seems she got your message.

Comment: Just because it's common, doesn't mean it'll happen.  Unless they start harassing you or something, just assume they got your edit, they implemented it, and that's the end of it.  You can't expect a thank you for every little thing you do at work, I'm sure they get 100 edit opinions a day, and don't have time to thank every one.

Comment: Cast final close vote. Suggested retitle and edit: "*I emailed a colleague about a minor mistake, which was then fixed, but never got a reply. [ Did I annoy her? / Did I do anything wrong? ]*".

Comment: put on hold as unclear what you're asking? I stated out the questions clear

Comment: @Acroneos, the comments and even the answer express that view: it is not clear why you think you got her annoyed. Having no answer isn't sufficient. As such your question is unclear. Nevertheless, I think you have your answer.

Comment: @Acroneos Is your question whether you annoyed her? Hard to know. An answerable question might be to ask about appropriate etiquette in this case (opinion based but probably answerable). The question about "did I annoy her" seems unanswerable. For example, if you send her another e-mail saying something like "Why didn't you reply??" that will definitely be annoying. After all, she did respond by carrying out the correction. That's much better than a sweet reply with no action.

Comment: @Acroneos You may have stated your questions clearly, but it is still unclear what you are asking for. We have no way to tell how she felt on reading your mail, as such it is unclear what answer you are looking for to  the question, "Did I annoy her?" It is also unclear what exactly you are trying to solve here. You sent her a mail, she fixed the problem. What else you want to happen next is unclear. Sorry for the nagging, but I hope this helps clarify why it is "unclear what you're asking". :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What have I done wrong? Why did I annoy the person?

You haven't done anything wrong. I also doubt she was more than momentarily annoyed. She's probably forgotten all about it now. It's much the same as me fixing a spelling error here, no need for a thank you.

So if you didn't get a thank you email, don't worry about it. Only worry if you got a nasty email.